# Retrieving and updating array from nested array MongoDB

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

I am hoping to get some help regarding querying nested documents and arrays in MongoDB as I am new to it and hit a roadblock.

I have a document with the following structure,

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5bd0fdfebc54ef73c6b2c841"
},
"name": "Joe",
"email": "joe@test.com",
"password": "$2a$10$6piR5uuLqZxEXbazwHBw7egFYJwnwEs3AYdpJGvlW1/cu6CGj1f8a",
"shows": [
    2790,
    13,
    4,
    1850
],
"ep_info": [
    {
        "show_id": "169",
        "no_of_eps": "62",
        "watched_eps": "1",
        "watched_eps_names": [
            "Pilot"
        ]
    },
    {
        "show_id": 2790,
        "no_of_eps": 39,
        "watched_eps": 0,
        "watched_eps_names": []
    }

]}
```

I have been trying to find out a way to be able to update the `watched_eps` and `watched_eps_names` fields depending on the given `email` to identify the user first and then the given `show_id` to find the correct nested array object.

I am sure I am missing something as I have only just started using MongoDB and when I search for similar solutions I don't really see something like this.

Would appreciate any help possible.

Comment: is the show_id unique in your ep_info array?

Comment: Yes, show_id is unique for each nested document in the ep_info array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below query:

```
db.getCollection('tests').update({
    "email":"joe@test.com", "ep_info.show_id" : "169"
},
{
    "$set": {"ep_info.$.watched_eps": 10, "ep_info.$.watched_eps_names" : ["Pilot", "abc", "def"]}
})
```

**Before:**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bd0fdfebc54ef73c6b2c841"),
    "name" : "Joe",
    "email" : "joe@test.com",
    "password" : "$2a$10$6piR5uuLqZxEXbazwHBw7egFYJwnwEs3AYdpJGvlW1/cu6CGj1f8a",
    "shows" : [ 
        2790, 
        13, 
        4, 
        1850
    ],
    "ep_info" : [ 
        {
            "show_id" : "169",
            "no_of_eps" : "62",
            "watched_eps" : "1",
            "watched_eps_names" : [ 
                "Pilot"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "show_id" : 2790,
            "no_of_eps" : 39,
            "watched_eps" : 0,
            "watched_eps_names" : []
        }
    ]
}
```

**After update:**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bd0fdfebc54ef73c6b2c841"),
    "name" : "Joe",
    "email" : "joe@test.com",
    "password" : "$2a$10$6piR5uuLqZxEXbazwHBw7egFYJwnwEs3AYdpJGvlW1/cu6CGj1f8a",
    "shows" : [ 
        2790, 
        13, 
        4, 
        1850
    ],
    "ep_info" : [ 
        {
            "show_id" : "169",
            "no_of_eps" : "62",
            "watched_eps" : 10.0,
            "watched_eps_names" : [ 
                "Pilot", 
                "abc", 
                "def"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "show_id" : 2790,
            "no_of_eps" : 39,
            "watched_eps" : 0,
            "watched_eps_names" : []
        }
    ]
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, it works fine with $set. However I tried using $inc and $push as so db.collection('users').update({
   "email":req.body.email, "ep_info.show_id" : req.body.show
  },
  {
   "$inc" : {"ep_info.$.watched_eps": 1},
   "$push" : {"ep_info.$.watched_eps_names": req.body.payload}          But I can't see the changes reflected in my database, is there anything wrong with the code I wrote?

Comment: tested, works perfectly for me. Perhaps something wrong with req params.

Comment: Yes, I have also tested and worked properly. @kako50 double check your data that you are going to insert.

Comment: Thank you both for your help, it was an issue with the formatting of the data being inserted.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Hardik Shah answer :

This will update only the first array element matching show_id criteria. If you can have multiple elements to update in the same array, you have to use [positional filtered operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) to match all array element that need to be upated.

Here's an example :

```
db['01'].update(
  {"email": "joe@test.com"},
  {$set:{"ep_info.$[elem].watched_eps":10,"ep_info.$[elem].watched_eps_names":["a","b","c"]}},
  {arrayFilters:[{"elem.show_id":2790}]}
)
```

Comment: Agree, If need to update all matched document `$[]` should use.